# jQuery on DOMNodeInserted plus html() causing endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a custom jQuery solution to labels that are incorrect - correcting a third party plugin we use that will require updating, so I don't want to edit the php code of the plugin, because once updated our edits will obviously disappear.

It's for a Select element that says 'My friends', which we want changed to 'My connections', and 'My friends in group" which we want changed to 'My connections in group."

The selector for this is re inserted via ajax when another select is utilized, so I need for this change to happen every time the selector is inserted.  Thus I have written the following code

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#wrapper').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#selector', function() {
                //alert('Friends inserted!');
                var title1 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-friends');
                if(title1.length > 0) {
                        title1.html('My Connections'); 
                }
                var title2 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-groupfriends');
                if(title2.length > 0) {
                        title2.html('My Connections in Group'); 
                }
                alert(title1.html() + ' ' + title2.html() );           
        }); // end on 
}); // end ready
```

If I comment out the html() functions, the code executes perfectly fine to let me know that the event was triggered.

If I try to let the html() functions commence, the code gets stuck in an infinite loop, and can never make the replacement.

Why is this causing an unintentional infinite loop?  How can I prevent or stop the loop?

Answer (score 3):

Figured a way out after all.  Add a class when it runs, and set the on function to not fire if it has that class.  When it's called again by the other selector, that class won't be there and it will fire again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#activity-visibility').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#activity-privacy:not(.altered)', function() {
                jQuery(this).addClass('altered');
                var title1 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-friends');
                if(title1.length > 0) {
                        title1.html('My Connections');
                }
                var title2 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-groupfriends');
                if(title2.length > 0) {
                        title2.html('My Connections in Group');  
                }
        }); // end on
}); // end ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You created the loop here:

```
 jQuery('#wrapper').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#selector', function() {
```

This is adding a handler for anytime that DOMNodeInserted happens.

Then once inside the method, you trigger the DOMNodeInserted when you do this:

```
 title2.html('My Connections in Group');
```

html() is adding new text, when triggers DOMNodeInserted again, and the cycle continues.

To fix, you need to disable the listener after it triggers the first time.

Add this inside the method:

```
 jQuery('#wrapper').off('DOMNodeInserted');
```

Comment: Where exactly should I place this?

Comment: Inside the if(title1.length>0) brackets, if(title2.length>0) brackets? or just before the end of .on()?

Comment: thus far it is still executing an infinite loop no matter where I place it :/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that events in Javascript propogate in bottom->up manner. Meaning that when you insert something into a child it triggers `DOMNodeInserted` of the child, but than propogates to the parent and triggers parent's `DOMNodeInserted`, and than to the parent of the parent, and so on until there is no parent. All events work this way.

You have a classical problem, but you have no means of preventing propagation when you insert html into your child nodes, thus you can do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#wrapper').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#selector', function(e) {

      if ($(e.originalEvent.relatedNode).is($('#selector'))) {
             //alert('Friends inserted!');
            var title1 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-friends');
            if(title1.length > 0) {
                    title1.html('My Connections in Group'); 
            }
            var title2 = jQuery(this).children('.fa-groupfriends');
            if(title2.length > 0) {
                    title2.html('My Connections in Group'); 
            }
            alert(title1.html() + ' ' + title2.html() ); 
      }

    }); // end on 

}); // end ready
```

`$(e.originalEvent.relatedNode).is($('#selector'))` - will ensure that the function will work only when something is directly inserted into `$('#selector')`

Comment: Since I'm altering the child elements .fa-friends and .fa-groupfriends, do I have to make separate wrappers for each of those instead?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'relatedNode' of undefined